# MySql SELECT statement to calculate ranking

Tags: php, mysql

table1

```
id  q1  q2  q3  q4  q5  q6
1   100 100 100 100 100 100
2   100 100 100 100 100 100
3   100 100 100 100 100 100
4   100 100 100 100 100 100
```

I have a mysql table with 7 fields and 4 rows of data as above "table1". Each q1 - q6 has a numeric value of let's say 100, to make it easy to understand if our equation works or not.

I want to do the following in my mysql query to get the result below (I have broken it into 2 steps to make it easier to understand but I need to do this in one MySql query):

1). SELECT q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6) AS ranking

The value of 200 should be returned for each database row AS ranking (based on the values of 100 per item in each row)

2). q1 + (q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6) / SUM(ranking)

OR

ranking / SUM(ranking)

So the value of 200 should be returned for each row: 200 / SUM(ranking)

This should equal 0.25 (200 / 800 = 0.25) (ranking / SUM(ranking))

I currently have the below MySql query which does not return the correct values as expected above:

```
SELECT *,
    (q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6)) AS ranking,
     (q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6) / (
        SELECT SUM(q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6)) 
        FROM data
        WHERE customer = :customer
    )) AS rankingSum
    FROM data
    WHERE customer = :customer
    GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY rankingSum
    DESC
```

The above query returns a value such as: 100,06

Not what I am wanting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing paranthesis at the first subquery.
You entered:

```
(q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6) / (
    SELECT SUM(q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6)) 
    FROM data
    WHERE customer = :customer
)) AS rankingSum
```

correct is:

```
((q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6)) / (
    SELECT SUM(q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6)) 
    FROM data
    WHERE customer = :customer
)) AS rankingSum
```

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate the sum and then use it:

```
SELECT @sum_ranking := (SUM(q1)*7 + SUM(q2) + SUM(q3) + SUM(q4) + SUM(q5) + SUM(q6))/6 FROM data;
SELECT (q1 + (q1+q2+q3+q4+q5+q6)/6) as ranking, (q1 + (q1+q2+q3+q4+q5+q6)/6)/@sum_ranking FROM data;
```

Answer (score 1):

rank/sum ?

```
SELECT *,
(q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6)) AS ranking,
 (q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6)) / (
    SELECT SUM(q1 + ((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5 + q6) / 6)) 
    FROM data
    WHERE customer = :customer
) AS rankingSum
FROM data
WHERE customer = :customer
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY rankingSum
DESC
```